# JArray replace value where condition match

Tags: c#, arrays, json.net

What is the best way to replace "NaN" with empty string in JArray?

Here are the example responses I get from remote server

Response 1:

```
 [{"id":-384958505,"Value1":"NaN"},{"id":426608375,"Value1":10},{"id":426608376,"Value1":"NaN"}]
```

Response 2:

```
[{"id":-384958505,"Value1":"NaN","Age":"NaN"},{"id":426608375,"Value1":10,"Age":"NaN"},{"id":426608376,"Value1":"NaN","Age":25}]
```

I would not know how many keys or key names before calling the remote server. I am currently using C# with NewtonsonftJson.

Comment: @stuartd -- what if there is a property named "NaN", not just a value?

Comment: Are you sure you want to replace them? NaN is a legal value for a floating point number, but an empty string is not. It seems like replacing these values would just get in the way of deserialization.

Comment: This seems like an X/Y problem

Answer (score 3):

You can use Newtonsoft's Json.NET [LINQ](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryingLINQtoJSON.htm) capabilities and `Replace`:

```
var parsed = JArray.Parse(json);
var en = parsed
    .Descendants()
    .OfType<JValue>()
    .Where(d => d.Value<string>() == "NaN");
foreach (var element in en)
{
    element.Replace(JValue.FromObject(string.Empty));
}
```

Comment: @Andy no, it will not.

Comment: @Andy also you can use `d.Type == JTokenType.String` filter to narrow the search.